# Equivalence $\displaystyle((\lnot p \lor q) \land (q \lor r)) \land (p \land \lnot q) ≡ c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I am trying to prove this. Using only laws. I am getting nowhere. The 3 variables on the left hand side keep tripping me up. I've tried DeMorgans, Distributive, Identity and Negation as a starting point but hit dead ends.

Comment: To be clear:  Is "c" meant to stand for "contradiction"?  Because the LHS is false.

Comment: Yes. Indeed. Contradiction; implying that no matter the values it will always be false, can be seen with a truth table.

Answer (score 1):

Distributing,
$$((\lnot p \lor q)\land (q\lor r)) \iff (((\lnot p \lor q)\land q ) \lor ((\lnot p \lor q)\land r)) \iff q\,\lor ((\lnot p \lor q)\land r)$$
$$\iff (\lnot p \lor q)\land (q\lor r) \iff \lnot(p \land \lnot q)\land (q\lor r)$$
Then the original expression is 
$$\lnot(p \land \lnot q)\land (q\lor r) \land (p\land \lnot q)$$
Which is false.

Comment: This doesn't prove that it is false however. it must simplify to a contradiction. Otherwise I could just use a truth table.

Comment: From that last line you have $((p\land \lnot q) \land \lnot(p \land \lnot q))\land (q\lor r)$. The first two terms are negations of each other, so their conjunction is a contradiction.

Comment: Ah Yes, I see that now. And so finally it would be Universal Bound Law p ∧ c ≡ c correct? I think I screwed up my first distribution by distributing the variables individually. Giving ((¬p∧q)∨(¬p∧r)∨(q∧q)∨(q∧r)) ∧ (p∧¬q) which in retrospect is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

> $$((\neg p\vee q)\wedge (q\vee r)) \wedge (p\wedge \neg q)$$

Use commutation, association, and deMorgan's to obtain:

$$(q\vee r)\wedge (\neg (p\wedge \neg q)\wedge (p\wedge \neg q))$$

Then you should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me make sense of it. Second term is now a contradiction.